SSRS: query execution failed for shared data set 'ID2023CRPList'. (rsDatarsErrorExecutingCommmand)
Web browser connection to SSRS reports not working correctly.  Receiving the following errors when trying to run SSRS report from remote cpmputer:
• An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) o The execution failed for the shared data set 'ID2023CRPList'. (rsDataSetExecutionError)
• Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
• For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
I'm new to SSRS network setup for web report accessibility. Trying to get the web browser connection to my SSRS reports working correctly. I have Active Directory security group set up under Settings> Site Settings> Security at the top level of my SSRS Home page as a System User: STPHA\Job_Fin_Acct_Specialist. This gives me top-level access to the folders I've set up & when I drill into the actual reports to run in Chrome Browser, it gives me the following error when running an actual report from a remote server:
• An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) o The execution failed for the shared data set 'ID2023CRPList'. (rsDataSetExecutionError)
• Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
• For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
Under Report Server Configuration Manager under Web Service URL/Web Portal URL, I currently have established http>//CAOSQL01:80/ReportServer as the url for users to access reports via Chrome web browser. In Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security on Local Computer, I've set up Port 80 as an Inbound Rule to allow connections from Domain/Private/Public access just to get things connected. Problem is, my network admin told me he does not want to allow this access through Port 80.
Questions to you:

Is there another Win Defender Firewall setup rule I can use to make the connection at the actual report level?
Do I need to set up specific computers to remotely access the reports in Win Defender Firewall?
Can you suggest other items for me to check on these errors?

Thx for your future time! JC
